# Identify word ongoing process (Document saving) using visual basic

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am saving a large word document and before the saving process completed , I am uploading the active document content to the server using our vb project. As the saving process is not completed, my code is giving an error saying,

```
Unexpected Error 70 - Permission Denied
```

Commands.TPS_UplodDocument

Is there any way to identify if the file saving process finished or not by using a visual basic code? 
I tried on this.

`Word.ActiveDocument.Saved`

But it is returning True just after the saving process started.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following vb code to identify a word document's saving process is in progress or not.

```
word.Application.BackgroundSavingStatus
```

This will return `0`  if there is no document saving process running.

This will return a `count <> 0` if the document saving process is in progress.

```
Do
    Select Case True
    Case mobjApplication.wordApp.BackgroundSavingStatus = 0
         Exit Do
    Case Else
         DoEvents
    End Select
Loop
```

This  will wait the project execution until the document saving process get completed.